# How to convert String to int in Java with value that contains numbers like this "1,2,3,4,5,6" and is converted into Array?

Tags: java, android, arrays, variables

I have code like this

```
 private void profileUser() {
    ApiServices api = InitLibrary.getInstance();

    Call<ResponseProfile> call = api.profile_request(username, api_key, userID);

    call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseProfile>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ResponseProfile> call, Response<ResponseProfile> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                String return_value = response.body().getReturnValue();
                data = response.body().getData();

                tvUsername.setText(data.getUserName());
                tvEmail.setText(data.getUserEmail());
                tvNoHp.setText(data.getMobile());

                String gender = data.getSex();
                switch (gender) {
                    case "1":
                        gender = "Laki-laki";
                        break;
                    case "2":
                        gender = "Perempuan";
                        break;
                    case "M":
                        gender = "Laki-laki";
                        break;
                    case "F":
                        gender = "Perempuan";
                }

                tvGender.setText(gender);
                tvBirthdate.setText(data.getBirthdate());

                String edu = data.getIdEdu();
                switch (edu) {
                    case "1":
                        edu = "SD";
                        break;
                    case "2":
                        edu = "SMP/sederajat";
                        break;
                    case "3":
                        edu = "SMA/sederajat";
                        break;
                    case "4":
                        edu = "Diploma";
                        break;
                    case "5":
                        edu = "S1";
                        break;
                    case "6":
                        edu = "S2";
                        break;
                    case "7":
                        edu = "S3";
                        break;
                    default:
                        edu = "Lainnya";
                }

                tvEdukasi.setText(edu);
                //=============================================================================================================
                List<Integer> exp_1;
                List<Integer> exp_2;
                List<Integer> exp_3;
                List<Integer> exp_4;
                List<Integer> exp_5;

                String experience  = (data.getIdExp());
                int exx = Integer.valueOf(experience);

                int[] research_exp = {exx};

                Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this, experience, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                exp_1 = Arrays.asList(research_exp[0]);
                exp_2 = Arrays.asList(research_exp[1]);
                exp_3 = Arrays.asList(research_exp[2]);
                exp_4 = Arrays.asList(research_exp[3]);
                exp_5 = Arrays.asList(research_exp[4]);

                Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this, exp_1.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                switch (exp_1) {
                    case 1:
                        exp_1 = Integer.parseInt("Belum punya pengalaman");
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        exp_1 = Integer.parseInt("Industri barang konsumen");
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        exp_1 = Integer.parseInt("Industri otomotif");
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        exp_1 = Integer.parseInt("Industri telekomunikasi");
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        exp_1 = Integer.parseInt("Industri perbankan");
                        break;
                    case 6:
                        exp_1 = Integer.parseInt("Industri real estate");
                        break;
                    case 7:
                        exp_1 = Integer.parseInt("Industri barang elektronik");
                        break;
                    default:
                        exp_1 = Integer.parseInt("Lainnya");
                }

               switch (exp_2) {
                case 1:
                    exp_2 = Integer.parseInt("Belum punya pengalaman");
                    break;
                case 2:
                    exp_2 = Integer.parseInt("Industri barang konsumen");
                    break;
                case 3:
                    exp_2 = Integer.parseInt("Industri otomotif");
                    break;
                case 4:
                    exp_2 = Integer.parseInt("Industri telekomunikasi");
                    break;
                case 5:
                    exp_2 = Integer.parseInt("Industri perbankan");
                    break;
                case 6:
                    exp_2 = Integer.parseInt("Industri real estate");
                    break;
                case 7:
                    exp_2 = Integer.parseInt("Industri barang elektronik");
                    break;
                default:
                    exp_2 = Integer.parseInt("Lainnya");
            }


                switch (exp_3) {
                    case 1:
                        exp_3 = Integer.parseInt("Belum punya pengalaman");
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        exp_3 = Integer.parseInt("Industri barang konsumen");
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        exp_3 = Integer.parseInt("Industri otomotif");
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        exp_3 = Integer.parseInt("Industri telekomunikasi");
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        exp_3 = Integer.parseInt("Industri perbankan");
                        break;
                    case 6:
                        exp_3 = Integer.parseInt("Industri real estate");
                        break;
                    case 7:
                        exp_3 = Integer.parseInt("Industri barang elektronik");
                        break;
                    default:
                        exp_3 = Integer.parseInt("Lainnya");
                }

                switch (exp_4) {
                    case 1:
                        exp_4 = Integer.parseInt("Belum punya pengalaman");
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        exp_4 = Integer.parseInt("Industri barang konsumen");
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        exp_4 = Integer.parseInt("Industri otomotif");
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        exp_4 = Integer.parseInt("Industri telekomunikasi");
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        exp_4 = Integer.parseInt("Industri perbankan");
                        break;
                    case 6:
                        exp_4 = Integer.parseInt("Industri real estate");
                        break;
                    case 7:
                        exp_4 = Integer.parseInt("Industri barang elektronik");
                        break;
                    default:
                        exp_4 = Integer.parseInt("Lainnya");
                }

                switch (exp_5) {
                    case 1:
                        exp_5 = Integer.parseInt("Belum punya pengalaman");
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        exp_5 = Integer.parseInt("Industri barang konsumen");
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        exp_5 = Integer.parseInt("Industri otomotif");
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        exp_5 = Integer.parseInt("Industri telekomunikasi");
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        exp_5 = Integer.parseInt("Industri perbankan");
                        break;
                    case 6:
                        exp_5 = Integer.parseInt("Industri real estate");
                        break;
                    case 7:
                        exp_5 = Integer.parseInt("Industri barang elektronik");
                        break;
                    default:
                        exp_5 = Integer.parseInt("Lainnya");
                }

                tvExperience.setText(Arrays.toString(research_exp));
}
```

I have a string variable, which contains a number, for example like this "1,2,3,4,5,6". But I want to convert it into an integer and converted again into an array variable. With the purpose of each number in it has its own variable value to be converted again into a string using the switch case, but the code I have does not work, so I ask for help, Thanks

Comment: Try something with `String.split()`, `Integer.parseInt()` and building arrays. Shouldn't be too hard.

Comment: exp_1 = Integer.parseInt("Belum punya pengalaman"); let me guess ... doesn't run well ?

Comment: of course, haha

Comment: Can you give a shorter example of what you are trying to do? Like shorter switch and only exp_1 instead of 1-5?

Answer (score 2):

`Integer.parseInt(String s);` needs a Number in a String like `"1"` or `"135"` The method can't convert text.

*This is not working*: `Integer.parseInt("Belum punya pengalaman");`

*This is working*: `Integer.parseInt("356");`